# Return large string from lua function in nodemcu lua

Tags: c, esp8266, nodemcu

i'm trying to modify nodemcu lua file.list functon /app/modules/file.c
to return a large string of filenames separated with newline char. currently it returns array and is very memory consuming also i'm stripping file size.
Here is what i have done (examined how some other functions return strings)

```
static int file_list( lua_State* L )
{
    char temp[32];
    unsigned st = luaL_optinteger( L, 1, 1 ); // start offset
    unsigned tf = luaL_optinteger( L, 2, 100000 ); // how much files to list
    tf=tf+st;
    vfs_dir *dir;

    if (dir = vfs_opendir("")) {
        lua_newtable( L );
        struct vfs_stat stat;
        int i=1;
        int ii=0;
        while (vfs_readdir(dir, &stat) == VFS_RES_OK) {
            if (i<st)
            {
                i++;
                continue;
            }
            if (i>=tf)
            {
                break;
            }
            strcpy (temp,stat.name);
            strcat (temp,"\n");
            lua_pushstring( L, temp );
            i++;
            ii++;
        }
        vfs_closedir(dir);
        return ii;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It do not work as expected, If I request more than 40 files (at once after device reboots) I see output like this:

```
....
3fff0d10 already freed
3fff11b8 already freed
3fff0cc8 already freed
3fff1f88 already freed
.....
```

and device restart, but if I request 30 files, and every time increase them in steps of 30, manage to get 400 files at one time.

```
=file.list(1,30)
=file.list(1,60)
=file.list(1,90)
```

that way it works, If I do directly:

```
=file.list(1,60)
```

it does not work. Noticed also that memory is allocated and not set free after function finished, but also not reallocate after same command execution so it is not memory leak, just some date stays in the stack perhaps.

Comment: Creating big strings in Lua is not a good idea.  Probably, it would be better to make an array of strings, each string is about 4Kb.

Comment: good suggestion, gonna try to make an array of few 3-4k strings, but I got some problem with the stack there not sure what.

Comment: It may be interesting for you to know that we just today merged an important improvement to the function into our `dev` branch: https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/pull/2452

Comment: Thank you, i was aware for that it is good improvement but do not fix problem with large number of files. I solve my problem by modify file.list to return an array of 1k filenames separated by new line. That way I list 580 files at cost of 8kb node heap. Since nodemcu team do not like my approach it goes at dead end - using for myself only.